# Restarting Application after crash on android 10+

Tags: android, exception, crash

I am using this code in an exception handler setting it as my default exception handler in my oncreate function
it is working on version 9 and less but not higher than that

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ActivitySplash.class);
        Log.w("excCaught", ex.toString());
        intent.putExtra("crash", true);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyApplication.instance.getBaseContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) MyApplication.instance.getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, pendingIntent);
        activity.finish();
        System.exit(2);
```

IS there a newer version to use the needed code ? or is there something that must be added in Manisfest for newer versions

allowBackup is true and supports RTLS

Comment: I think you need to set more delay for 2 second instead of 100 millis.

Comment: @pratikvekariya even with an increased amount of mlliseconds it isn't working !

Comment: remove activity.finish() and set System.exit(0) and try.